# CGVector amount changes when changing scenes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In my first scene I have a `CGVector` value that makes a ball bounce around the screen. When loading back to this screen (from a game over screen), the value has changed making the ball move much slower than I want.

First scene `addBall` method:

```
CGVector ballDirection = CGVectorMake (40,120);
[ball.physicsBody applyForce:ballDirection];
```

Moving back to the first scene from game over scene:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    MyScene *firstScene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:firstScene transition:[SKTransition doorsOpenHorizontalWithDuration:0.5]];
    SKAction *playAgainSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"opening.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
    [self.scene runAction:playAgainSound];
}
```

Not sure why the `CGVectorMake` value appears to have changed as the `addBall` method will get called in `initWithSize` when transitioning back to the first scene.

I tried the following without success:

```
static CGFloat dx = 40;
static CGFloat dy = 120;
CGVector ballDirection = CGVectorMake(dx, dy);
[ball.physicsBody applyForce:ballDirection];
```

Comment: you need to have a reference to to ballDirection because it's reinitialised taking a random value. or change it to static instead

Comment: That does not make any sense. If you apply a set vector to your ball the first time, move to another scene, go back to the first scene and apply the same vector again - the ball will move at the same vector. Obviously your issue is not with the code you posted but something else. Review your code again step by step or post more relevant code.

Comment: If it is the same scene which you are coming back to, init will not get called. Also, where in the code are you calling applyForce?

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of using [ball.physicsBody applyForce:BallDirection]; I used "applyImpulse" after testing, the ball reloads with the correct values.